# I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't boot it from the USB

Tags: installation, dual-boot

My Windows 8 is 64 bit version and the Ubuntu ISO that I downloaded is the 32 bit version. The problem is that downloading it took a long time because of my slow connection. Is there a way I could install it alongside Windows 8 64 bit?

I recently had Windows 7 on this same machine and I updated Windows later. At that time, I could easily install Ubuntu along side Windows 7.

Need some help on this guys.

Comment: **First,** Check the iso for errors by [calculating the MD5SUM for the iso.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) **Then** follow the [instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported) to **disable Fast Startup.**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer depends if you have UEFI or not.  If you do, and Windows 8 is setup using it, then you need the 64bit version.  Only 64 bit version currently has the UEFI secure boot capability, since only new computers support UEFI.

For more information take a look at [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)